# Python. Проблема в списках и циклах

Tags: python, циклы, список, for

Нужно напечатать все разные слова и указать для каждого количество повторений в тексте. До этого нужно было разбить текст на список по коме и убрать точку, но с этим, вроде бы, проблем нету и успешно это сделал. Есть вот ошибка в 7 и 8 строке, вместо переменной z я могу сделать print и оно будет успешно выводить, но оно выводит не так как нужно. Хочу что бы вывод был так, что каждое слово только по одному разу и около него цифра, сколько раз повторяется.
Мой код:

```
text = input("текст: ")
#Nastya, Cat, Eat, Nastya, Love.
text = text.replace(".", "")
words = list(text.split(", "))
b = words
z = 0
for i in b:
    z = (i, words.count(i))
print(z)
print(list(set(words)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, что-ли

```
text = input("текст: ")
#Nastya, Cat, Eat, Nastya, Love.
text = text.replace(".", "")
words = list(text.split(", "))
b = set(words)
z = 0
for i in b:
    z = (i, words.count(i))
    print(z)
```

Результат:

```
('Cat', 1)
('Nastya', 2)
('Love', 1)
('Eat', 1)
```

Comment: Да, большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Реализация с помощью встроенной либы collections

```
    from collections import Counter
    
    text = input("текст: ")
    
    c = Counter()
    for word in text.replace(" ", "").replace(".", "").split(","):
        c[word] += 1
```

Примеры принтов результатов

```
    >>> print(c)
    Counter({'Nastya': 2, 'Cat': 1, 'Eat': 1, 'Love': 1})
    
    >>> c.keys()
    dict_keys(['Nastya', 'Cat', 'Eat', 'Love'])
    
    >>> c.values()
    dict_values([2, 1, 1, 1])
    
    >>> for i in c.items():
    ...    print(i)
        
    ('Nastya', 2)
    ('Cat', 1)
    ('Eat', 1)
    ('Love', 1)
```

Подробнее про [Counter](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-collections.html)

Comment: Так использовать `Counter` не выгодно, `Counter(text.replace(" ", "").replace(".", "").split(","))` будет и проще и быстрее